# Linear SGD Classifier not training without data scaling?

Tags: classification

I'm training SGD Classifier before I apply scaling it only gives accuracy of 0.02. After I apply scaling, the accuracy is 0.85. What could be the problem?

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", n_jobs=-1, max_iter=1000).fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the User Guide Tips for Practical Use:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#tips-on-practical-use
Stochastic Gradient Descent is sensitive to feature scaling, so it is highly recommended to scale your data. For example, scale each attribute on the input vector X to [0,1] or [-1,+1], or standardize it to have mean 0 and variance 1. Note that the same scaling must be applied to the test vector to obtain meaningful results. This can be easily done using StandardScaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)  # Don't cheat - fit only on training data
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)  # apply same transformation to test data
```

Without seeing your data and your model, it's hard to say what's going on. For example, is your data set skewed? Looking at precision/recall/F1 scores as well as the confusion matrix can also sometimes help understand what is going well/what is going wrong with classifiers. hth

Comment: Yes, my data is indeed skewed. I updated my post with some results. What can you conclude from such results?

Comment: Interesting - your data is indeed skewed towards "other" (~71%), but it's predicting "eueowl1" over 99% of the time. These must be the results for the unscaled/unnormalized inputs - can you post for the scaled inputs? How does the data look before scaling? Is the mean for eueowl1 class much higher (or lower) than everything else? It definitely demonstrates why input scaling is a good idea ;) thx